# Python - How to Count & Remember Number of Occurrences in a Loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Hopefully i can explain as clear as possible of what i'm trying to do.

I'm running a while loop every 2 seconds to get updated values from 2 different stores that have different values:

the dictionaries looks like this:

```
#2 seconds
{'lastUpdateId': 202588846, 'store1': [['24.43000000', '0.00606000'], ['24.42000000', '14.76000000'], ['24.39000000', '2.65760000'], ['24.38000000', '29.59867000'], ['24.35000000', '7.71171000']], 'store2': [['24.47000000', '0.22601000'], ['24.52000000', '0.72000000'], ['24.53000000', '3.28839000'], ['24.54000000', '5.63226000'], ['24.55000000', '20.64052000']]}
#2 seconds
{'lastUpdateId': 202588904, 'store1': [['24.45000000', '0.22596000'], ['24.44000000', '12.84000000'], ['24.43000000', '22.43211000'], ['24.42000000', '5.87234000'], ['24.39000000', '2.65760000']], 'store2': [['24.51000000', '0.00003000'], ['24.52000000', '2.80979000'], ['24.53000000', '17.64938000'], ['24.67000000', '3.41000000'], ['24.68000000', '115.07610000']]}
```

Now what i want to do is compare inside of a loop the second value from store 1 to the second value of store 2, i want to count up to 10 times if 10 is counted then

i want it to continue to the next line of code, but this is where i'm stuck i don't how to do this, what can i do for python to remember the loop counts?

here is what i have tried so far:

```
import time
def testing():

    stores = {'lastUpdateId': 202588846, 'store1': [['24.43000000', '0.00606000'], ['24.42000000', '14.76000000'], ['24.39000000', '2.65760000'], ['24.38000000', '29.59867000'], ['24.35000000', '7.71171000']], 'store2': [['24.47000000', '0.22601000'], ['24.52000000', '0.72000000'], ['24.53000000', '3.28839000'], ['24.54000000', '5.63226000'], ['24.55000000', '20.64052000']]}

    firststore = [i[1] for i in stores['store1']]

    secondstore = [e[1] for e in stores['store2']]

    offer1 = float(firststore[0]) + float(firststore[1]) + float(firststore[2])


    offer2 = float(secondstore[0]) + float(secondstore[1]) + float(secondstore[2])


    count = 0

    if offer1 > offer2:

        count+=1

        print("This store has the lesser better deal")

        if count == 10:
            print("go ahead and buy")

    if offer2 > offer1:
        count+=1
        print("this other store has the lesser letter deal")

        if count == 10:
            print("go buy this")

i = 0
while True:
    i+=1
    testing()
    time.sleep(2)
```

could provide me with a better idea? maybe with a for loop and append?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a generator. [Here](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) is a great explanation of generators and how they work.

I broke out your comparison code into a separate generator function, which is assigned to generator object `offer_comparer` by calling the generator function `compare_offer`. The the `next` call starts function execution and returns at the first `yield`.

Then, each call to `offer_comparer.send(<params>)` sends offer1 and offer2 to the `offers` variable in the generator function.

This should give you what you're looking for.

```
import time


def compare_offers():
    count_max = 10
    while True:
        count1 = 0
        count2 = 0
        while count1 < count_max and count2 < count_max:
            offers = yield
            offer1, offer2 = offers[0], offers[1]
            if offer1 > offer2:
                count1 += 1
                print("Store1 has the better deal")
                if count1 == count_max:
                    print("go ahead and buy from store1")
            elif offer2 > offer1:
                count2 += 1
                print("Store2 has the better deal")
                if count2 == count_max:
                    print("go buy this from store2")


offer_comparer = compare_offers()
next(offer_comparer)


def testing():
    stores = {'lastUpdateId': 202588846,
              'store1': [['24.43000000', '0.00606000'],
                         ['24.42000000', '14.76000000'],
                         ['24.39000000', '2.65760000'],
                         ['24.38000000', '29.59867000'],
                         ['24.35000000', '7.71171000']],
              'store2': [['24.47000000', '0.22601000'],
                         ['24.52000000', '0.72000000'],
                         ['24.53000000', '3.28839000'],
                         ['24.54000000', '5.63226000'],
                         ['24.55000000', '20.64052000']]}

    firststore = [float(i[1]) for i in stores['store1']]
    secondstore = [float(e[1]) for e in stores['store2']]

    offer1 = sum(firststore[:3])
    offer2 = sum(secondstore[:3])

    offer_comparer.send((offer1, offer2))


i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    testing()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) to count & remember the number of occurence in your loop :

```
for count, item in enumerate(list):
    if (count+1) % 10 == 0 and offer2 > offer1:
        print("go buy this")
    elif (count+1) % 10 == 0 and offer1 > offer2:
        print("go buy this")
```